setting the 'ramp-up period' to 0 to test for race condition on jmeter
according to the documentation, the ramp-up period is described as follows:

The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun.

then should I set the ramp-up period to 0 if I want to test for race conditions in a specific API request? I want to verify if the application responds correctly when 100 users simultaneously request the API.

If you want to send 100 requests at exactly the same moment - add a Synchronizing Timer to your HTTP Request sampler and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to 100.
In case you want 100 users to hit the API endpoint for particular period of time - consider setting reasonable ramp-up period, for example 50 or 100 seconds so the load would increase gradually. As per JMeter documentation:

Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

This way you will be able to correlate the increasing load with other metrics like throughput, response time, number of errors, etc.
More information: JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide
